# What happens to $y=\ln x$ when it is translated and then dilated?

Tags: functions

I am struggling to understand my teacher's answer for the following question.

> The curve $y=\ln x$ is translated to the left by $\pi$ units and then dilated horizontally by a scale factor of 3. What is the equation that describes the new curve?

I thought it was $y=\ln(x/3 +\pi)$ since the translation is applied first, which isn't typical order. But my teacher has the answer as $y=\ln\frac{x+\pi}3$, which would make sense to me if the order was dilation then translation, but I'm struggling to understand how that comes from translation then dilation.

Is my teacher correct, and if so, can someone explain?

Comment: @Henry, thank you! so the dilation is applied to pi as well as the x?

Comment: for clarification, would the result be any different if the dilation was performed before the translation?

Comment: @MW - Indeed - I will delete the initial comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A curve $y=f(x)$ translated to the left by $\pi$ results in a curve $y=f(x+\pi).$

A curve $y=g(x)$ dilated horizontally by $3$ results in $y=g(x/3).$

Your teacher is therefore wrong and you are right.

If the dilation was performed before, it would be the opposite.

Comment: Im not sure!! I'm not downvoting it!!!! I really appreciate your answer it seems fine to me

Comment: $y = \ln(x)$ first becomes $y = \ln(x + \pi)$. Writing $g(x) = \ln(x + \pi)$, this is $y = g(x)$, so next this becomes $y = g(x/3) = \ln(x/3 + \pi)$.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but it looks to my eye like teacher is wrong and OP is right

Comment: Omg thank you! I correct immediately!!

Comment: actually, In my textbook it says that doing dilation first gives f(a(x+b), while doing translation first gives f(ax+b). That suggests to me that it should be ln(/3+)  , but am I just misinterpreting the textbook?

Comment: @user1213971 no you were correct all along.

Comment: Oh for real?? cool!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys!!!

Comment: @user1213971 If you think this post answers your question/gives you the most insight, you may want to mark it as accepted it by clicking/tapping the check button. (This is to remove it from the unanswered section.)

Comment: Oh yeah perfect, sorry I am new, didn't know I could do that lol!!